# Struggling to web-scrape dynamic code with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping

I'm experimenting with trying to webscrape some of the data used in a graph on a particular website, but struggling, with this content hidden and dynamic.

I've tried strategies using finding an element based on an xpath, but having no joy. I've provided screenshots of the image where I'm looking to extract the annotations ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCtPg.png)) and the line of code that I'm unable to locate using Selenium ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amm9i.png))

If anyone can provide any tips / pointers, that would be great

Edit - Link is here: https://www.similarweb.com/website/vodafone.com/

Examples of code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class = "highcharts-tooltip"]')
sel.xpath('//*[@text = "tspan"]').extract()
```

Comment: Please provide links and your relevant code, not pictures

Comment: No worries - see the above edit - appreciate your time

Comment: OK, what exactly data are you want to scrape? What elements etc?

Comment: Sure - i'm looking to get the annotations on the graph (i.e. month and number of visits)

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482367/how-to-scrape-values-on-hovering-highcharts-using-selenium-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scrape values on hovering highcharts using selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482367/how-to-scrape-values-on-hovering-highcharts-using-selenium-python)

Comment: This does (and wish I'd found the link earlier) - @prophet - really grateful for all your help in solving this!